# Macbook pro wont boot, Kernel cache read error 0x6

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, kernel

I have recently installed *macOS Sierra* and sometimes my *Macbook pro mid-2012* boots up properly (rarely). Otherwise it does not boot. When I try to boot it with *cmd+v* , it shows following text:

**Read error 0x6**

**Kernel cache read error 0x6**

It's been days since Im facing this issue. Any solution? Right now I'm asking this question using my Mac because it was of of those good times when it did boot properly.

Comment: Did you fix it? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

There's probably some sort of corruption in the kernel or Kernel cache.

Best bet would be to backup your data first, just in case, then restart and boot to your recovery volume by holding Command and R before you see the Apple logo.

Eventually you'll be at a window with a few options including reinstalling Mac OS. If you're using wifi then connect to it in the top right corner of the screen. Choose the Reinstall option and follow the prompts, eventually selecting your boot drive as the Reinstall volume.

It might take up to a few hours but you'll have a fresh operating system while preserving your data and should get rid of the kernel issue.